# Changing display modes in blender 2.8

Tags: interface, versions

I downloaded the daily blender build from the 2.8 branch a few days ago to try out some new features. I found that some of the interface has changed, especially that the display modes button is missing.

The default mode is rendered. How can I change that to solid or wireframe?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an unreleased unsupported version of Blender

Comment: Any chance the off-topic could be made clear in the help center itself? Or one usually has to go to meta for this? Stack exchange seems to imply there is a defined scope in the help center ("This question does not appear to be about Blender within the scope defined in the help center."), while there really isn't much over there.

Comment: This is a very recent situation, I don't think the help center has been updated to reflect that. Also very localized one, once 2.8 is releases it wouldn't be an issue any more. There is some discussion about it here https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/are-questions-about-the-2-8-branch-on-topic

Comment: It won't be an issue for 2.8 anymore, but it will still be an issue for future versions. So maybe an overall "questions about unreleased versions are off-topic"? Yeah, I already jumped to meta and caught that one. A little too late, but oh well.

Comment: You should bring that up in the meta site then. Feel free to post a question mentioning this thread. I am sure some of the moderators might be interested in adding it to the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2.8 builds are work in progress so that they can test features and introduce work that needs to be considered - but these builds are not complete and finished for production, and they might not be ready for all use cases just yet. I also wonder about where the wireframes will come in since I use them for some cases when painting and masking, but for now I stick to the 2.78c where my addons work.